# WP8 LongListSelector firing SelectionChanged event when CheckBox is clicked

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a simple data template for the new Windows Phone 8 LongListSelector as follows:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,-6,0,-10">
        <CheckBox x:Name="ToDoCheckBox" Margin="0" IsChecked="{Binding ItemIsComplete}" Checked="ToDoCheckBox_Checked"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

There are suppsed to be a few more items in the template, that's why CheckBox's content property hasn't been used.

Now, I have page navigation implemented on SelectionChanged event. Problem is that, SelectionChanged even is fired even when the CheckBox is clicked. Earlier questions seem to discuss exactly opposite issue. I do not want SelectionChanged to be fired. Or, at least I don't want page to navigate on CheckBox events. I just want to have checkbox checked or unchecked event. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selection is a bad way to trigger navigation. Without digging into that, you can avoid this by triggering the navigation when the other item in the template is tapped.
e.g.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,-6,0,-10">
        <CheckBox x:Name="ToDoCheckBox" Margin="0" IsChecked="{Binding ItemIsComplete}" Checked="ToDoCheckBox_Checked"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"
                   TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
                   FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"
                   Tap="TriggerNavigationToThisItem"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The above assumes you have an event called `TriggerNavigationToThisItem` which will trigger the navigation. You could also add a command on the Item and bind to that to trigger the navigation.

If you have a more complex template you could encapsulate them in a container (like a `Grid`) and then have that trigger the navigation.

Comment: Though I have marked you as an answer, I'd like to know why is selection a bad way to do navigation!

Comment: @akshay2000 short answer: selection is a bad way to trigger navigation as it's easy to accidentally trigger a selection when you're actually trying to do something else, such as scroll. A `Tap` event is a much better navigation trigger as it's much harder to accidentally trigger a tap event when swiping or scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the original source of en every selection changed event. If it is the checkbox - simply skip execution.

Also. Don't use native "LongListSelector.Selected" property and selection event at all. It has completely no scalability (for example for multiselection). Implement it with your own Tap event handling.

Comment: I need some explanation! How do I check the original source of execution? Why are people so much against SelectionChanged and SelectedItem?

Comment: On the Tap event handler e.OriginalSource returns you an original FrameworkElement which has been tapped. You can try CheckBox ifCheck=(CheckBox) e.OriginalSource. And if ifCheck!=null that means the checkbox was the original source and you don't need to mark this list item selected.